# How to apply jrtx style for static text in jrxml file

Tags: jasper-reports

I have an issue on staticText tag into jrxml template.

I'm using *iReport 5.0.4* and *JasperReports* to apply a jrtx style to my default jrxml template.
As soon i apply the style, every element labeled as staticText disappears.

As soon i remove the style, everythig show correctly. This seems strange, because other tags such as textField works properly,and i can change background color, font etc.

Maybe i do need to apply some tag properties, but i can't figure what is missing. The style is referenced with the tag. Please help on this

Answer (score 0):

I found mistake and its working now and shared below code

```
<jasperTemplate>
        <style name="rptlnbl" isDefault="true" hAlign="Center" vAlign="Middle"
            fontSize="24" fontName="Arial" pdfFontName="Helvetica" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="false">

    </style>
</jasperTemplate>
```

earlier i am  updated isDefualt is false.After setting true and able seen jrtx file changes in jrxml.